# how to get Google calender ruleId?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to transfer my calendar ownership to another user. I see on google API documentation needs `ruleId`

I didn't find any way to get `ruleId`

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: try checking [acl.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl/list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can proceed to create a [ACL list method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl/list) to list data from your Calendar.

This is because according to the documentation of the [ACL get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl/get) method, the RuleID is the ACL [rule identifier](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl). So the ID under this part below should be the RuleID.

> "calendar#aclRule"